# How to insert data from listbox into database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, listbox

I have a listbox with two buttons. The first button to add a file into the listbox. The second button to delete it from the listbox.

And there is a third button I want to use it to insert the files from the listbox to the SQL Server database.

For example if I added two files into the listbox I want to save them in my database after clicking on insert button.

Sorry for my poor English; I hope someone can help me

```
// this button for adding files to listbox
private void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        OpenFileDialog parcourir = new OpenFileDialog();
        parcourir.Filter = "XML Files (.xml)|*.xml|All Files (*.*)|*.*";

        if (parcourir.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(parcourir.SafeFileName);
        }
}

//this button for deleting selected file in listbox
private void delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            if (listBox1.SelectedIndex < 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("select a file first", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            else
            {
                listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
            }
        }
        else
        {  
            MessageBox.Show("listbox empty", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation); 
        }
 }

 private void insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    //save files from listbox to sql database
 }
```

[image]

Comment: What is your research into this so far ? What is your database ? how does your tables lookes like. How do you connect to your database ? You need to tell us something we can use else nobody can help you

Comment: thanks @GuidoG
I'm using sql server .. I have a databse DB.mdf
I want to save the files into a table FILES which contains 3 columns :
number_file (auto_increment)
name_file
path_file

Comment: I think a simple ADO.Net search would be enough to resolve this

TIP: Use CommandBuilder

Comment: @BèlguesmiSémah thanks for the info, but it should be in your question not in a comment. Everybody reading your question should have all the info he needs without reading all the comments.

Answer (score 2):

not tested it but this should get you on your way :
This assumes that the listbox has a full path+name for each file.

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(yourconnectionstring))
{
    connection.Open();
    foreach (string item in yourListBox.Items)
    {
        string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item);
        string filePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(item); 

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO FILE (name_file, path_file) VALUES (@fileName, @filePath)", connection))
        {
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileName", fileName);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filePath", filePath);
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```